# How to view rails/routes for a rails engine in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails engine, which is mounted in `dummy/config/routes.rb` using

```
mount Handicap::Engine => "/handicap"
```

In the engine, I have a number of controllers, and when I start a rails server in the dummy directory these routes are active e.g. /handicap/tees/index responds. However, when I go to `/rails/routes` it only shows:

```
handicap_path       /handicap   Handicap::Engine
rails_routes_path   GET /rails/routes(.:format) sextant/routes#index
sextant_engine_path     /sextant    Sextant::Engine
```

I can list them using `rake routes`, but my normal work flow is to list them in the browser.  How do I list the engine routes in the browser?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you only want to show your routes in the browser in development mode, there's a rails page which you can call:

http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes (available since Rails 4)

If you're upgrading from rails 3, you can remove the sextant gem from your gems as this is now part of the rails core.

---

If you want to show your routes in production to the user, you can implement it like the following: (implemented in `bin/rake routes` ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake)) you can call the same things from your code:)

## Attempt 1:

Controller code:

```
# app/controllers/example_controller.rb

routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
@inspector = ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector.new(routes)
```

View Code:

```
# app/views/example/show.html.erb

# Yeah! There's also a HTML Table Formatter already to print routes in html
inspector.format(ActionDispatch::Routing::HtmlTableFormatter.new(self))
```

## Attempt 2:

Do this in a helper:

```
# app/helpers/route_printing_helper.rb

module RoutePrintingHelper
  def print_routes(view)
    routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
    inspector = ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector.new(routes)
    inspector.format(ActionDispatch::Routing::HtmlTableFormatter.new(view))
  end
end
```

And then call it:

```
# app/views/example/show.html.erb
print_routes(self)
```

## Attempt 3:

This is the "cheapest" way of doing this:

```
# app/controllers/example_controller.rb

@routes_output = `#{Rails.root}/bin/rake routes`
```

Your view:

```
# app/views/example/show.html.erb

<pre><%= @routes_output %></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, there is some cool information in there that may be useful for me later if I want to present this information to a user.  However, right now I am interested in development mode. Unfortunately, ```/rails/info/routes ``` does the same as ```rails/routes``` i.e. it does not print out the routes in the engine.  Your attempt 3: will do this, but I am hoping someone can show a way to do this without writing custom code.

Comment: @Obromios It's been a long time, but would you mind accepting my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out, the clue was the line:

```
sextant_engine_path     /sextant    Sextant::Engine
```

This indicated that I still had the [sextant gem](https://github.com/schneems/sextant) in my Gemfile. Sextant was the way of doing this in rails 3, and as noted by [siegy22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3906189/siegy22), it has not been needed since rails 4.  The solution was simply to take sextant out of the gemfile.  Given the project is on rails 5, it was about time!